# Application to Website authentication

Tags: authentication

I'm new to Wordpress. I'm working on an application that takes in user information and checks it on my website. If the user exists, continue, else, Quit. I know this is possible with REST api but use in production environment is discouraged because it sends username and password every time.

I need a safe way of authenticating to my site and receiving Username and User ID in my Application (Java).
Please help me!

(If I've missed anything please let me know I will update my question)

Comment: Yes, there are application passwords now for the REST API, and you can install plugins that add JWT authentication etc. too. As long as you're accessing the REST API over HTTPS it ought to be OK anyway.

Comment: Or do you mean the user enters their WordPress credentials into your app? That's not the modern way, no. Could you set up your WordPress site as an OpenID connect or OAuth2 server and authenticate against it that way, i.e. users only type their passwords into a window from your actual site?

Comment: But if you do want to use the username and password to log in over the REST API and then continue using the API, maybe the [JWT Auth](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-auth/) plugin? You log in once with username and password to generate a token, then use the token for all further requests. There may be better ways to do this.

Comment: @Rup Hi! Thanks for the comment. I just want a way for my application to confirm that the user using my application has an account on my website. So the user inputs some information like a username and we can check if that username exists on site to give access. I've been looking into JWT Auth and this might be the way.